# Detect start & end of a C declaration without a full C parser

Tags: c, parsing

I would like to *partially* parse a list of C declarations and/or function definitions.

That is, I want to split it into substrings, each containing one declaration, or function definition.

Each declaration (separately) will then be passed to another module (that *does* contain a full C parser, but that I cannot call directly.)

Obviously I could do this by including another full C parser in my program, but I hope to avoid this.

The tricky cases I'e come up against so far involve the question of whether `'}'` terminates a declaration/definition or not.  For example in

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {return 0;}
```

... the `'}'` is a terminator, whereas in

```
typedef struct foo {int bar;} *pfoo;
```

it is not. There may also be pathological pieces of code like this:

```
struct {int bar;} *getFooPtr(...) { /* code... */ }
```

**Notes**

- Please assume the C code has already been fully preprocessed before my function sees it.  (Actually it hasn't, but we have a workaround for that.)
- My parser will probably be implemented in Lua with [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/)

Comment: In my experience, whenever you try to fake a significant non-trivial portion of a parser, you end up writing so much code, and your code becomes so non-readable so fast, that you regret not using a full parser to start with. What's wrong with a full parser, anyway? As far as free, well-debugged, high-usage grammars go, it's hard to beat C, especially after [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Parser.html) project became available.

Comment: C is incredibly hard to parse with a "simple" parser.  Too little syntactic sugar and too many obscure forms of declarations.

Comment: If "parsing" C language declarations were as trivial as searching for closing curlys, **everyone** would be doing it. That they're not should tell you something about the complexity of the problem you are, in fact, trivializing.

Comment: @WhozCraig, not "everyone" because typically when you want to parse C declarations, it is because you are writing a compiler.  I am trivializing it because the information I need is trivial compared to what the compiler writer needs.

Comment: Your end-use may be trival; it none-the-less does not make that task so. Take a *valid* formal C99 grammar. Buried in that grammar is a location where a production *defines* the finish of a function definition. Likewise with a type declaration, etc. All the productions, etc, that were needed to get to that point are, *by defintion of the language grammar* mandated to reliably reach the production that dictates "yup, its a function definition". Effort to cut that out *will* lead to faltering unless *your* grammar can find a reliable way to bypass the intermediates. And that is *not* trivial.

Comment: You don't even know if it *is* a declaration unless you parse it properly. The meaning of `a * b` is totally different if it is preceded by `typedef int a;` or `int a;`.

Comment: @BoPersson: That does not matter as long as I know where it ends.  Both end at the semicolon (and in the case of the *expression* `a * b` it must start and end inside the function body, which I will be skipping over.)

Comment: Don't forget the possibly pathological `struct{int(bar);}typedef(*pfoo),(foo);`

Comment: @MichaelBurr, that is not valid C is it?

Comment: @finnw: I believe it is valid C (though it might be deprecated in C90 or C99. I'm really not sure, but GCC gives a warning about it if `-Wold-style-declaration` is enabled). GCC compiles it as C or C++, while MSVC compiles it as C.  MSVC has trouble with it when compiled as C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the state machine in your answer to deal with function definitions add the following steps:

1. set fun/var state to 'unknown'
2. Examine the character at the current position
3. If it's `;`, we have found the end of the declaration, and its not a function definition (might be a function declaration, though).
4. If it's `"` or `'`, jump to the matching quote, skipping over escape sequences if necessary.
5. If it's `(`, `[` or `{`, jump to the matching `)`, `]` or `}` (skipping over nested brackets and strings recursively if necessary)
6. If fun/var state is 'function' and we just skipped `{` .. `}`, we've found the end of the declaration, and its a function definition
7. If fun/var state is 'unknown' and we just skipped `(` .. `)`, set fun/var state to 'function'.
8. If the current char is `=` or `,`, set fun/var state to 'not-function`.
9. Advance to the next input character, and go back to 2.

Of course, this only works on post-pre-processed code -- if you have macros that do various odd things that haven't yet been expanded, all bets are off.

Comment: Since you guys appear to be cribbing from the same source, perhaps you could identify the source.

Comment: I just copied finnw's answer and added a little bit.

Comment: I think this would misidentify non-functions that are declared using parens, like `int (a);` or `int (*a)();`

Comment: @rogual: finding a ';' that is not enclosed in something that makes us skip it always ends a declaration, regardless of what state we're in (so the 'function' state just means it might be a function, not that it is a function -- getting a ';' means it is not a function.)

Comment: Oops, just saw that you're excluding function declarations from being functions, whereas I wasn't. Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the following solution works for *declarations* only (that is, function definitions must be kept out of this section, or adding semicolons after them may be a workaround:)

1. Examine the character at the current position
2. If it's `;`, we have found the end of the declaration.
3. If it's `"` or `'`, jump to the matching quote, skipping over escape sequences if necessary.
4. If it's `(`, `[` or `{`, jump to the matching `)`, `]` or `}` (skipping over nested brackets and strings recursively if necessary)
5. Otherwise, advance to the next input character and goto step 1.

If this proves to be unsatisfactory, I will switch to the *clang* parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to extract the part of the C grammar which is related to declarations, and build a parser for that or an abbreviated version of that.   Similarly, you want the grammar for function bodies, abbreviated in a similar way, so you can skip them.

This might produce a relatively trustworthy parser for declarations.

It is unfortunate that you will not likely be able to get your hands on a trustworthy C grammar; the one in the ANSI Standard(s) is not the one the compilers actually use.   Every vendor has added goodies and complications to their compiler (e.g., MS C's declspecs, etc.).

The assumption the preprocessor has run is interesting.  Where are you going to get the preprocessor configuration? (e.g., compiler commmand line defines,  include paths, pragma settings, etc.)?  This is harder than it looks, as each development environment defines different ways to set the preprocessor conditionals.

If you are willing to accept occasional errors, then any heuristic is valid candidate,
modulo how often it makes a mistake on an important client's code.  This also means you can handle un-processed code, avoiding the preprocessor issue entirely.